# Still Unable to Import OpenAI Error Module After PyCharm Update - Deprecation?

Tags: python, pycharm, openai-api

Running Python 3.11.6

Trying to import error handling functionality via:

```
from openai.error import OpenAIError
```

```
Getting the error "cannot find reference" 'error' in '__init__.py'
```

I've updated Pycharm, updated OpenAI in my MACOS via terminal (pip install openai==1.3.7) and (pip install upgrade open ai), and even updated the settings for Pycharm and Python themselves.

Does anyone know if that module has been deprecated?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the name of your script?

Comment: Make sure you don't have a file named 'openai.py' in your directory.